# Fluoride Bluetooth stack

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-8.0-oreo

why in recent releases of android it changed the bluetooth stack from `Bluedroid` to `Fluoride` ?

1. is there any differences between `Bluedroid` and `Fluoride`? if yes what are they?
2. From where i can get architecture/reference for `Fluoride Bluetooth stack`

Answer (score 1):

1. It was just a name change. Since they also provided Ubuntu support, I would guess that they did re-branding in order to make it more appealing for Linux usage. The name Bluedroid itself might stick out a bit in this environment.